# Drupal 7 display specific field from node in Block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've created a content type with the fields below to store testimonials:
name
testimonial
pullout_quote
image

My client would like to display the pullout_quote and name field in a block.  However, they want this to be as easy to achieve as possible (not using views).  Simply add the content and tick to display this testimonial on xxx/xxx page

I thought that using nodeblock module would work but this pulls all the content into the block, not just the specified fields.

Can anyone offer any pointers or advice because i've spent hours on this and am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with block display and pass node I'd as an argument. Then add the fields you want to display. This is the quickest way.